# How can I get the title of a post for another one?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a Q&A website and there is a table named `questions_and_answers`.

I know this structure isn't good *(keeping both questions and answers in the same table)*, but I don't want to change it.

**TABLE : questions_and_answers**

```
+----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
| id |   title  |      content      | user_id | related |
+----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
| 1  | title1   | content1          | 105     | NULL    | -- related column is null for questions
| 2  |          | content2          | 56      | 1       | -- related column contains the id of its question
| 3  | title2   | content3          | 2235    | NULL    |
| 4  |          | content4          | 56      | 1       |
| 5  |          | content5          | 321     | 3       |
| 6  | title3   | content6          | 56      | NULL    |
| 7  | title4   | content7          | 874     | NULL    |
| 8  |          | content8          | 1001    | 6       |
+----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

All I'm trying to do is selecting all questions and answers of a specific user. Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM questions_and_answers WHERE user_id = 56;
```

**Output:**

```
   +----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
    | id |   title  |      content      | user_id | related |
    +----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
    | 2  |          | content2          | 56      | 1       |
    | 4  |          | content4          | 56      | 1       |
    | 6  | title3   | content6          | 56      | NULL    |
    +----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

And my question is, how can I fill `title` column for answers by the title of its question?

This is the **expected result**:

```
    +----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
    | id |   title  |      content      | user_id | related |
    +----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
    | 2  | title1   | content2          | 56      | 1       |
    | 4  | title1   | content4          | 56      | 1       |
    | 6  | title3   | content6          | 56      | NULL    |
    +----+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: This structure is poor, you're right. You'll save yourself this headache now, and more in the future, by normalising the tables properly. I know you said you want to keep it, but I think that's the wrong decision. You've created a structure which is really unsuited to how SQL queries work. All you really need to do is put the questions in a separate table, and make "related" a foreign key to that table, instead of a key to another row in the same table.

Comment: @ADyson What you said is true and I knew it. But it's a university task and that structure is designed by our teacher. I cannot modify it.

Comment: Are you sure your teacher wasn't setting you a challenge to see if you'd spot the bad design and modify it? That might be a way to get extra marks? Either that or your teacher is just bad at database design.

Comment: @ADyson I discussed about that challenge at classroom few days ago. But that structure is just an example. That's a simplified of a theory to teach us `self-join` concept.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess a better example would have been one where there wasn't an alternative, properly normalised design, but never mind!

Comment: You can always try to normalize it by introducing views.  One for questions where `related IS NULL` and one for answers, where it isn't.  Then you can just query the views like they are separate tables.  And you won't have to change the queries when you do normalize the tables in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE` statement as below:

```
SELECT qa.id
    ,CASE 
        WHEN qa1.title IS NULL
            THEN qa.title
        ELSE qa1.title
        END AS title
    ,qa.content
    ,qa.user_id
    ,qa.related
FROM questions_and_answers AS qa
LEFT JOIN questions_and_answers AS qa1 ON qa.related = qa1.id
WHERE qa.user_id = 56;
```

Also, using 'IFNULL'

```
SELECT qa.id
    ,IFNULL(qa1.Title,qa.Title) title
    ,qa.content
    ,qa.user_id
    ,qa.related
FROM questions_and_answers AS qa
LEFT JOIN questions_and_answers AS qa1 ON qa.related = qa1.id
WHERE qa.user_id = 56;
```

Demo link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5600e/24

Comment: `title` column is never `NULL`. It is either empty or contains a string.

Comment: Understood. But due to left join if matching record is not found then it is null not in the table. I have added demo link. Please check

Comment: Can you please edit your aliases and replace `qa` and `qa1` with `questions`and `answers`? I need to understand how your query works.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but hope this Logic is fine.

Try this:

**Solution 1:**

```
SELECT T1.ID,CASE WHEN T1.Title = '' THEN T2.Title ELSE T1.Title END Title, T1.Content , T1.User_ID,T1.Related
FROM questions_and_answers T1
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT A.content,B.ID,B.Title
    FROM questions_and_answers A
    JOIN questions_and_answers B ON A.Related=B.Id
    )T2 ON T1.content=T2.content
WHERE user_id = 56;
```

**Solution 2:**

Instead of this You can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT T1.ID,CASE WHEN T1.Title NOT LIKE '%title%' THEN T2.Title ELSE T1.Title END Title, T1.Content , T1.User_ID,T1.Related
FROM @questions_and_answers T1
LEFT JOIN @questions_and_answers T2 ON T1.Related=T2.Id
WHERE T1.user_id = 56;
```

**Result:**

```
ID  Title   Content     User_ID Related
--  -----   --------    ------- -------
2   title1  content2    56      1
4   title1  content4    56      1
6   title3  content6    56      NULL
```

Comment: `title` column is never `NULL`. It is either empty or contains a string

Comment: One question, I guess doing that is possible with only one `LEFT JOIN`. Why did you used both a `LEFT JOIN` and  a `subquery` and a `JOIN` in it? Doesn't seem optimal to me.